# Change Google One Tap Sign-in positon with javascript

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, google-authentication

```js
google.accounts.id.initialize({
            client_id: '111111111111.apps.googleusercontent.com',
            cancel_on_tap_outside: false,
            callback: handleCredentialResponse
        });

        google.accounts.id.prompt();
```

I am prompting the UI with Javascript but I can't find a way to set a new position to the popup. 
I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution in the api documentation. I create an iframe in my html file;

```
 <div id="g_id_onload"
      data-prompt_parent_id="g_id_onload"
      data-cancel_on_tap_outside="false"
      style="position: absolute; left: 79%; top: 124px; width: 0; height: 0; z-index: 1001;">
 </div>
```

After that I add this iframe to the api's initialization as a parameter: `prompt_parent_id: 'g_id_onload'`

```
google.accounts.id.initialize({
            client_id: '111111111111.apps.googleusercontent.com',
            cancel_on_tap_outside: false,
            callback: handleCredentialResponse,
            prompt_parent_id: 'g_id_onload'
        });

google.accounts.id.prompt();
```

Then I can play with the styling however I want.

You can find the detailed explanation in here: https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/guides/change-position